# Need Sql Queries for the scenario

Tags: sql-server

```
Trans Id  Date       Description       Credit        Debit 
1         12/05/2009 Amount Deposited   1000          1000
2         15/05/2009 Amount withdrawn   -500          500
3         20/05/2009 Deposited          2000          2500
4         25/05/2009 Amount withdrawn   -1000         1500
                             1500
```

Trans ID is the primary key

I need the output as follows

```
Trans Id  Date         Description       Amount
1         12/05/2009   Amount Deposited  1000
2         15/05/2009   Amount withdrawn  500
3         20/05/2009   Deposited         2000
4         25/05/2009   Amount withdrawn  1000
                       balance         1500
```

Need Sql query to generate the output

Comment: What have you done so far? What SQL have you got? The stackoverflow community will not do your work for you, especially if you don't show your efforts first.

Comment: And can you **explain** what you want to do?? You only show the original data and the output.... what do you want to do to your original data to get that output?? Group by? Filter by? Sort ? Please explain!! Otherwise we're left to simply guess......

Comment: Your last column in the 1st data set should be "balance", no?

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT TransId, Date, Description, ABS(Credit) AS Amount
FROM transactions
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, 'balance', SUM(Credit)
FROM transactions;
```

Result:

```
TransId  Date        Description       Amount
1        2009-05-12  Amount Deposited  1000            
2        2009-05-15  Amount Withdrawn  500             
3        2009-05-20  Deposited         2000            
4        2009-05-25  Amount Withdrawn  1000            
NULL     NULL        balance           1500
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a case statement to find the maximum, and abs to ensure a positive number:

```
select  [trans id]
,       date
,       description
,       abs(case when credit > debit then credit else debit end) as Amount
from    YourTable
```

Re-reading your question, I doubt this is the answer you're looking for.  Please explain in a bit more detail.